# Navigate based on redux store updates

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm having a react-native application using redux and react-native-router-flux with user authentication and I want to navigate to the main screen when the user is authenticated (no matter how this authentication is made) and to the login screen when the authentication token is invalid (no matter when or how this happens).

My first thought was to make the navigation in the reducer like this:

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        //navigate to main screen
        Actions.main();
        return {
            ...state,
            token: action.payload.token,
            loading: false
        }
```

The problem is that in this case the navigation happens before the state is updated and I get in the situation that I render the main screen but my token from the store is not updated yet.

I can solve the login case by checking the state in my login component but for the logout case which can happen in any component I don't know how to make something general.

How should I make my app navigation based on modifications in the redux store?

Comment: Why don`t  separate login from navigation?

Comment: May be use react-native-simple-store to store app session data and update store session data to app state. If session is present in app state then load login else go for main component with navigation.